# Many to Many: Delete one side, the relationship entry BUT don't delete the other side

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, cascade, nhibernate-cascade

I want to delete an user which has many usergroups but those usergroups don't belong exclusivly to this user: other users can also be using this usergroups. And usergroups can exist even if no user references them.

I want to map the many-to-many relationship so that if a **user is deleted**, the **relationship is automatically deleted** but ***NOT* the usergroup**?

I tried `Cascade.All` as I thought cascades on many-to-many affect the relationship but not the other side. I thought that only `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan` would do the otherside delete. Obviously I'm wrong.

It seems that I don't understand the cascade rules right. Can someone provide a clear explanation to me and maybe also a way to reach my goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NHibernate `many-to-many` relation does provide what we expect, let me explain it in more details. While we need only two entities **User** and **Group**, we will need Three tables: `User`, `Group`, `UserGroup` (with columns *UserId*, *GroupId*)

**C#** entities:

```
public class User {
   IList<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Group{
   IList<User> Users{get;set;}
}
```

**hbm.xml** our mapping will look like this:

```
<class name="User" ...    
  <bag name="Groups" lazy="true" 
       table="UserGroup" cascade="none" >
    <key column="UserId" />
    <many-to-many class="Group" column="GroupId" />
  </bag>
  ...

<!-- and group vica versa -->

<class name="Group" ...
  <bag name="Users" lazy="true" 
       table="UserGroup" cascade="none" >
     <key column="GroupId" />
     <many-to-many class="User" column="UserId" />
  </bag>
    ...
```

This mapping with important setting `cascade="none"` will do expected behaviour. This mapping says that there is a *PairTable* `UserGroup`, which does not have any entity representation. So, there cannot be any cascade setting effecting this table. This table is used *hiddenly* behind the scene.

**Pair table**

When some user is deleted, then *NHibernate* will aslo remove all the relations from the `UserGroup` table (in fact this will be the first statement in the batch). This is just the *relational reference constraint handling*. We cannot leave any `UserId` in the table `UserGroups`, which does not have its foreign key in the `User` table.

**The other relation end**

Finally the cascade setting: Because the `UserGroup` table is managed without any our attention, the *cascade* is in this case applied to entity `Group` - the other relation end. So setting it to all-delete-orphan could lead to complete deletion of all cross referenced records.

Summary: cascade on a `bag` with `many-to-many` relation is meant for the other end point, not the pairing table.

Comment: Thank you! I did some testing... Cascade.None (or Cascade.SaveUpdate) works. What seems important is that one (only one!) side of the association is inverse. The if the inverse=false side is deleted it works as expected. If the inverse=true side is deleted, a foreign-key exception is thrown... but it works if its collection is emptied before, which means manually removing the association... I guess there's no way around that, right?

Comment: I was using both. Mostly Cascade.None. Because usualy I have both ends already in the system (or at least `Group`s when adding new `User`), then *Cascade.None* will still insert into PairTable. Exceptionally we used Cascade.SaveUpdate, and it is wokring as expected;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler Yeah, every time I was trying to delete a row in one table, it deleted the other raw too. Didn't know, that cascade option was for the other table, not the link table. Thanks :)